# How to update the entire Eclipse RCP application built with Tycho using update site?

Tags: tycho

I built my RCP application using Tycho. I need the ability to update my product through update site. Normally update site allows to updates individual features (due to  [Tycho bug 361722](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361722) it's currently not possible). But I really need just to udpate the whole product through update site, not some specific features. So is it possible to adjust update site that way?

Comment: You are just saying that you have the same problem as others, but failed to implement the proposed solutions, without saying what your actual problems were. This doesn't make [a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No, I'm saying that I don't need to update individual features (so there's no point getting into details here), just the whole product. And such approach is not explained anywhere.

Comment: Well, the you should edit the question because as it stands now you have made at least three readers completely miss that point. E.g. if you don't want to update individual features, why do you link to questions and bugs related to that?

Comment: Hopefully the question is clarified now.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the product defined in a `*.product` file in an `eclipse-repository` module is included in the p2 repository build result. So when you build a new version version of you `eclipse-repository` module with a new version of your product, installations of previous versions of your product can be updated by using the new p2 repository.